# Running just one Test suites with Maven not working

Tags: maven, selenium, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have in my pom.xml two test suites

```
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <file>src/test/resources/weekly.xml</file>
                    <file>src/test/resources/monthly.xml</file> 

                     <!-- <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>  -->

                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I'm trying to run only one from the command line with mnv test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/monthly.xml 
Is running both of them and generate repost for both of them.

How can I run only one xml?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and executed the pom.xml. If you want to pass the xml file location at the runtime, your pom.xml should look like

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

You can use the maven command mentioned as below to execute :
mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/resources/.xml

Comment: thanks, but the path was incorrect, I added the full path D:....src/test/resources/monthly.xml and it works. I'm running the test from Jenkins from an external server, here was a challenge too.